# change the alpha for the background color of the canvas

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, canvas

Hi guy i am trying to clone colol wheel picker from [adobe color wheel](https://color.adobe.com/create/color-wheel),
i am having a problem with changing the alpha for the color wheel, the code i used to generate the color wheel is referenced from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46214072/color-wheel-picker-canvas-javascript).Below is the code i use to change the alpha for the background of the canvas(default alpha is 255), but it's not working, i still can't figure out why

```
useEffect(() => {
    const canvas = canvasRef.current;
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    let ImageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    for (var i = 0; i < canvas.height; i++)
      for (var j = 0; j < canvas.width; j++)
        if ((i + 1) % 4 === 0) {
          ImageData.data[i] = 150;
        }
    ctx.putImageData(ImageData, 0, 0); //put image data back
  }, []);
```

you can find full code and demo in [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/patient-glade-xb22wv?file=/src/Canvas.js), thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If changing the alpha is what you need, you should be using the canvas globalAlpha:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalAlpha

Here is an example drawing the same shape with different alpha values

```js
canvas = document.getElementById("cv0");
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
ctx.fillStyle = "red"

function draw(x, y, alpha) {
  ctx.globalAlpha = alpha
  ctx.beginPath()
  ctx.moveTo(x, y)  
  ctx.arc(x+20, y-10, 30, 0, 6)
  ctx.fill()
  ctx.globalAlpha = 1
}

draw(10, 40, 0.4)
draw(80, 40, 0.7)
draw(150, 40, 1)
```

```html
<canvas id='cv0' width=200 height=90></canvas>
```

---

When you provide a sample snippet please remove all other functions, variables and anything else that is not relevant to the problem at hand, read this for more info:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
that will save a lot of time to everyone reading your code for the first time, and you increase your chances of getting a fast response.

---

Here is my changes to your code snippet:
https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-fog-q303zf?file=/src/Canvas.js

I'm using the globalAlpha to draw two circles *(like yours just smaller)* with different alpha

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you want to change the alpha value of each color component contained in the `ImageData` array, are you?

In this case your for-loop is simply wrong. For illustrative purposes try something like this:

```js
let canvas = {
  width: 100,
  height: 20
};
let values = [];
for (var i = 0; i < canvas.height; i++)
  for (var j = 0; j < canvas.width; j++)
    if ((i + 1) % 4 === 0) {
      values.push(i);
    }
document.getElementById("result").innerText = values.toString();
```

```css
#result {
  width: 20em;
  display: block;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<span id="result"></span>
```

If you run the code above you'll notice that the only unique values we get are **3**, **7** ,**11**, **15** and **19**.

If you want to change the alpha of the whole ImageData array, you simply need to loop over it and change any 4th value.
For example:

```
let ImageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
for (let i = 0; i < ImageData.length; i += 4) {
    ImageData.data[i] = 150;
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work, it returns error "Potential infinite loop: exceeded 10001 iterations. You can disable this check by creating a sandbox.config.json file." It seems that your approach will cause the code to fall into an infinite loop

Comment: My code is surely not the problem - I guess you're simply trying to call that bit of code too often. As I can't look into your mind to see how you want that color wheel to work it's a bit hard to give you advice. For instance I can't really make out what background color you want to change anyhow. At the moment the code above just loops through any color contained inside the target canvas and changes it's alpha value to 150.

Comment: actually i'm looking to do a similar function as you can see in this [link](https://www.canva.com/colors/color-wheel/), a small point can be moved around the outermost circle to change the alpha background color wheel

Comment: and where in your codesandbox link is the actual background color you want to change based on the color that was clicked inside the circle?

Comment: the circle area contains the color wheel, you can go to this [adobe wheel](https://color.adobe.com/create/color-wheel), there will be five colors with 4 sliders each, try to adjust the 4th slide, it will make the color wheel darker or lighter, that's what I want to achieve

Comment: I see what you mean but there is nothing comparable in your code (no outher wheel, no slider, nothing that would trigger an alpha change on user interaction)

Comment: yes, that's why i wanted to find a way to change the alpha for the background first. But it's okay I'll try Helder Sepulveda's way